# Bash: replacing multiple words in file using dictionary template?

Tags: bash, dictionary, sed, translation, substitution

I'd like to write a script that does the following to its input: matches words from a template and replaces them by the corresponding equivalents (or "translations").

I used `case esac` for the dictionary template, which I tried putting into a loop before calling sed for the substitutions, but I'm not sure where to start and how to go about doing this. How to substitute parts of a file's content by the definitions of a template dictionary in a bash script?

Input (a file containing the following):

```
Sliced bread is the best thing since bread slicers.
```

Dictionary Template:

```
case "$@" in
sliced) Peanut butter ;;
bread) sandwiches ;; 
is) are ;;
"the best thing") even better. ;;
since bread slicers) "";;
*) "$@" ;; esac
```

Desired Output:

```
Peanut butter sandwiches are even better.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your dictionary is already written in bash, you could tokenise the input stream and pass each word independently to your dictionary. However, since you insist on allowing whitespace inside your words (like in `"the best thing"`) the tokenisation approach will not do. So you have to parse your dictionary and construct `sed` expressions from it.

Now, assuming the only non alphanumeric/blank character is `*` in the last line, you could do this:

```
s="$(cat "dict.bash" | sed -n 's/^[ \t]*\("\?\)\([^*")]\+\)\("\?\))[ \t]*"\?\([^\/"]*[^ \t]\)"\?[ \t]*;;.*$/\2)\4/p' | while IFS=")" read pat subst; do

  echo -n "s/$pat/$subst/gi;"

done)"

sed -e "$s"
```

However, since your dictionary must be applied incrementally, you end up producing intermediate strings that do not match the rules in your dictionary.